# Populate JSDoc index.html page

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I am starting out with `jsdoc` and `docdash` and everything seems to be going ok so far. However, even though my modules and such are slowly being documented I haven't figured out how to add items to the `index.html` file that is generated. What markup is required in the files to generate items into the root HTML file?

For more reference, at the top of the left-hand navigation pane is a "Home" link. This is what I am referring to when I am asking this question. The link goes essentially to a blank page, but all the other links below this have the correct documentation from the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://usejsdoc.org/about-including-readme.html) is somewhat misleading in how to do this. It says that as long as a README.md file is located within your source directories it will use the first file it finds as the index.html file.  This isn't entirely true. You also have to specify a path to the README.md file you want to use:

```
jsdoc -c jsdoc.json --readme ./README.md
```